# Calculating relative dates using asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, date

What is the best library for displaying relative dates (eg: 20 minutes ago) for ASP.NET MVC using in C#?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I calculate relative time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11/how-do-i-calculate-relative-time)

Comment: For .Net core Install-Package ChronicNetCore. https://www.nuget.org/packages/ChronicNetCore/

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You don't need a library when a simple extension method can do it. This is an extension method that I have used:

```
public static string TimeAgo(this DateTime date)
{
    TimeSpan timeSince = DateTime.Now.Subtract(date);
    if (timeSince.TotalMilliseconds < 1) return "not yet"; 
    if (timeSince.TotalMinutes < 1) return "just now";
    if (timeSince.TotalMinutes < 2) return "1 minute ago";
    if (timeSince.TotalMinutes < 60) return string.Format("{0} minutes ago", timeSince.Minutes);
    if (timeSince.TotalMinutes < 120) return "1 hour ago";
    if (timeSince.TotalHours < 24) return string.Format("{0} hours ago", timeSince.Hours);
    if (timeSince.TotalDays < 2) return "yesterday";
    if (timeSince.TotalDays < 7) return string.Format("{0} days ago", timeSince.Days); 
    if (timeSince.TotalDays < 14) return "last week";
    if (timeSince.TotalDays < 21) return "2 weeks ago";
    if (timeSince.TotalDays < 28) return "3 weeks ago";
    if (timeSince.TotalDays < 60) return "last month";
    if (timeSince.TotalDays < 365) return string.Format("{0} months ago", Math.Round(timeSince.TotalDays / 30));
    if (timeSince.TotalDays < 730) return "last year"; //last but not least...
    return string.Format("{0} years ago", Math.Round(timeSince.TotalDays / 365));
}
```

[Source Link](http://www.blog.ingenuitynow.net/Extension+Method+For+DateTime+TimeAgo.aspx)

Comment: An anonymous user submitted a suggested edit with the title *Kelsey, can you fix your code for the following: When timeSince.TotalDays == 1.9243, it's returning "1 days ago"*, suggesting a bug on the "yesterday" line.  It should be a comment rather than an edit, but I don't think the user is able to post comments.

Answer (score 6):

[timeago: a jQuery plugin](http://timeago.yarp.com/)

How about this?
But this is jQuery plugin. not c#.

Comment: I'd personally use this option, it does the heavy lifting on the client instead of the server which would be important for sites with a lot of traffic. You can't cache "minute ago" type information.

Answer (score 1):

Humanizer is a fantastic library for this. It is on nuget and includes lots of other great conversions for strings and enums in addition to dates.

https://github.com/MehdiK/Humanizer

Comment: Humanizer has bugs with TimeSpan. See [here](https://github.com/Humanizr/Humanizer/issues/583)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any established library that exists for this but http://tiredblogger.wordpress.com/2008/08/21/creating-twitter-esque-relative-dates-in-c/ should get you started.