# Parsing a DateTime instance

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I got a class with some time utility methods. Now I need to add to that a method the does the following:

```
    public static string LastUpdated(DateTime date)
    {
        string result = string.Empty;

        //check if date is sometime "today" and display it in the form "today, 2 PM"
        result = "today, " + date.ToString("t");

        //check if date is sometime "yesterday" and display it in the form "yesterday, 10 AM"
        result = "yesterday, " + date.ToString("t");

        //check if the day is before yesterday and display it in the form "2 days ago"
        result = ... etc;

        return result;
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like you are on the right track. What specifically is holding you up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well...you can do this...

```
if (date.Date == DateTime.Today) {
    result = "today, " + date.ToString("t");
} else if (date.Date.Day == DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1).Day) {
    result = "yesterday, " + date.ToString("t");
} else {
    result = (new TimeSpan(DateTime.Now.Ticks).Days - new TimeSpan(date.Ticks).Days) + " days ago";
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I believe that should do the job. Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

I answered a similar question a while back and posted an extension method:

[Calculating relative dates using asp.net mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682364/relative-dates-asp-net-mvc/3682673#3682673)

Original source [link](http://www.blog.ingenuitynow.net/Extension+Method+For+DateTime+TimeAgo.aspx)

Comment: That is not what I really wanted. I already have a similar function, but yours is a little bit better so I replaced mine with yours. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this:

[Calculate relative time in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11/how-do-i-calculate-relative-time/12#12)

This is how they do in StackOverflow. It should get you in some good direction.

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the time difference between the date and the coming midnight, and get it as whole days. From that it's easy to translate it into a human readable text:

```
int days = Math.Floor((DateTime.Today.AddDays(1) - date).TotalDays);
switch (days) {
  case 0: return "today, " + date.ToString("t");
  case 1: return "yesterday, " + date.ToString("t");
  default: return days.ToString() + " days ago";
}
```

Note: The switch doesn't handle future dates. You would have to check for negative values for that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to code this for you, but I will say that you should look at the [`TimeSpan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) class, and also take a look at the [Custom Date and Time Formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) page on MSDN, which hilights how you can use `.ToString()` with a `DateTime` object.

You should check if the date is greater than 1 day old (or 2, or 3 or whatever) and then return the appropriate string.